# Update Query With Inline

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

Is it possible to do an update query like this?  It may not be, just a thought I had as to *possibly* a solution to my predicament of terrible data-structure.  What I am trying to accomplish is:

To update the table prodinformation with a count where the entrytype exists in table vet

```
Set @location varchar(100), @entrydate datetime
Set @location = 'server01.database01.dbo.manhunt
Set @entrydate = GetDate()  

Update prodinformation
Set totalenteredtoday = abc.te
FROM prodinformation d
JOIN (SELECT Count(ID) 
      from @location 
      WHERE entrytype IN (
                          Select validentrytype 
                          from vet
                          where ltrim(rtrim(entrydate)) = @entrydate) As te
```

Comment: You're missing a join condition and it isn't clear why you are joining onto a single row result returned by `count`?

Comment: @MartinSmith - what I am wanting to accomplish is to update the table prodinformation with a count where the entrytype exists in table vet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update  d
Set     totalenteredtoday = te.IdCount
FROM    prodinformation As d
        JOIN 
        (
            Select   [someJoinAttribute]
                    ,Count(ID) As IdCount
            From    @location 
            Where   entrytype IN (  Select  validentrytype 
                                    From    vet With (Nolock)
                                    Where   ltrim(rtrim(entrydate)) = @entrydate
                                 )
            Group By [someJoinAttribute]
        ) As te On d.[someAttribute] = te.[someJoinAttribute]
```

here [someJoinAttribute] would be the column/attribute to be used to perform join operation